# How to push enemy back with a force when it's hitted?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im working on simple battle system in Unity, I have already added damage system but I want to upgrade it and push enemy back whenever he gets damage. I have made some tries but nothing worked correctly. Here is a litte bit of my code. I already appreciate for any suggestions.

```
public class EnemyTakeDmg : MonoBehaviour
{

     public int health = 8;
     private Rigidbody myBody;
     public float knockBackForce = 5f;


    public event System.Action OnDeath;

    private void Start()
    {
        myBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        health -= damage; // TAKING DAMAGE
        // PUSHING ENEMY BACK ???
    

        if(health <= 0)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }



public void Die()
{
    if(OnDeath != null)
    {
        OnDeath();
    }
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you show the code that makes a call to `TakeDamage` ?

Comment: Well. So far there doesnt look to be any code like you tried. What do you think you might need to know?

Comment: In words: Have a status called "stunned" or similar, and disable unity movement if status is "stunned". On taking damage, set status stunned. Apply knockback logic (addforce or velocity in direction opposed from damage source [player.position - transform.position]) then remove the stunned status so unit can move again.

Comment: Please define `hit` ... Do you have some kind of raycast or collision detection system?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to somehow get a reference to the object that made the shot. This is necessary to calculate direction of the knockback.

After that, it is pretty easy!

```
public void TakeDamage(int damage, Transform shooter)
{
   //Take damage
   health -= damage;

   //Knockback
   Vector3 direction = (transform.position - shooter.position).normalized;
   myBody.AddForce(direction * knockBackForce);
}
```

The direction might be the opposite, so you may need to switch `shooter.position` and `transform.position`.

Comment: `The direction might be the opposite` no probably not ;) A vector is always calculated `endPoint - startPoint` so if you want to get knocked away from the shooter this would be the way to go